# How to add to html page ES6 modules when one module contains only one class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am not very good with ES6 modules, and after reading many articles still can't understand the following. I want to have in one module one class, as we have in java. Because it is very convenient to have one file for one class. But I can't understand how to add these modules to browser, because, if I have as a rule more 100 classes then, as I understand, I will have to use more then 100 `<script src="..."></script`> in web page what is very bad solution. Could anyone say, how to add to html page ES6 modules when one module contains only one class?

Comment: I'm afraid you can only use a compiler to do it. I don't think browser support `import`

Comment: Let them `import` each other, that way you only need to put a `<script>` tag for the main module in your page?

Comment: or you can import all the functions in a single main.js file and include it in your html. but compiling and adding as a single file is the actual way to go IMO

Comment: @Bergi Do I understand you right - you state that I need to add one `<script>` to page, browser will download that script and after parsing it browser will donwload and other modules?

Comment: @Pavel_K yes, that's how modules work.

Comment: @Bergi I see, but making more 100 requests to webserver is not good solution either.

Comment: @Pavel_K That's what [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) solves. If you want to serve everything as a single file, a bundler is your only option.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for your answer. And the last question - do I understand right, if I use a bundler all my code will be in one js file and in this file there won't be any import/exports? By other words, as I understand it is not possible to have multiple modules in one file.

Comment: @Pavel_K Whether it still has imports and exports (and in what style) depends on your bundler (or its configuration), but yes there won't be individual modules that import each other any more.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The go-to way is to use a bundler like https://webpack.js.org/ that would spit out a single `bundle.js` which you then add to your page by using an "HtmlWebpackPlugin" or just adding the `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` manually. Actually, using webpack to just bundle up the javascript is pretty easy and requires minimal configuration.